# Can't find the scanned image

Tags: return-value, os.system

I used `os.system` to call the `scanimage` command, it works fine but I can't find the scanned image !
any help?
thanks in advance

```
 os.system ('scanimage > ~/test.pnm')
```

Comment: Does it work with an absolute path?

Comment: No, Directory nonexistence error !